# assign int to byte vs double to float in java

Tags: java

1.when we assign **double to float variable** compiler gives us error

```
float f = 2753.2211;
```

**possible loss of precision** Required to cast.

2.when we assign **int to byte variable** compiler don't  gives us error

```
byte b = 24;
```

**OK**

In second case data can also be lost.Then why casting explicitly is not necessary.?

Comment: try `byte b = 123456;` and see what happens

Comment: it gives error. but in first case double is also size of float.

Comment: It is not lost yet because 24 fits in a 8bits. When you will try what @Lucas suggested there will be a loss of precision because that number cannot fit in 8 bits without a loss.

Comment: check the answer below. There will be no data loss in your second example.

Comment: but data is also not losing in first case.Then why to cast.?

Comment: @Kartik_Agarwal data *will* be lost in the first case. The float closest to 2753.2211 is 2753.22119140625, you can get closer with a double. But this isn't the reason why it's not allowed.

Answer (score 11):

The second case is explicitly allowed by the JLS as a special case. In [JLS 5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2), which deals with narrowing conversions, it says:

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression ([§15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)) of type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.
>
> ...

In other words, for the non-`long` integer-like values, you can implicitly narrow them *iff* the value you're narrowing is a constant that fits within the type you're specifying.

I'm guessing the same trick isn't applied to floats because floating point values are trickier than integer values. For instance, 0.1 can't be exactly expressed in a floating point, while 1.0 can. That means that `double d = 0.1` isn't *actually* putting the value 0.1 into `d` -- just a value that's very close to 0.1. Given that, the "does it fit exactly" rule doesn't apply even to floating point literals, and the question of "does it fit exactly when we narrow" becomes trickier. Your options would basically be:

- always allow it (which could cause some surprising behavior if a value is significantly different than its literal representation)
- only allow it if the value *can* be exactly put in. This would look highly inconsistent:

  - `float f1 = 1.0` and `double d1 = 1.0` both work
  - `double d2 = 0.1` works, but `float f2 = 0.1` doesn't -- confusing!
- never allow it (slightly inconvenient, because you have to type the `f` char in the literal)

Given these options, it seems that the designers of the JLS chose the least of three not-great options.

Comment: I assume the same thing is not available for double because it would appear random. `0.5` can be converted losslessly, but `0.1` cannot.

Comment: @njzk2 That would be my (strong) guess, too -- but the JLS doesn't specify it, and I didn't write the JLS, so I don't have any evidence of it. But I'll add a bit to that effect. :)

Comment: then why error in `byte b=10;byte c=20;byte d=b+c;`

Comment: @Kartik_Agarwal Because `b+c` is not a _constant expression_ that this part of the JLS explicitely requires.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose first b+c will calculate and forms a int value and assigning it to byte is error but direct assigning int to byte is not a error..Why so..?

Comment: @Kartik_Agarwal Again, it has to be a _constant expression_, which is precisely defined in [JLS 15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). `b+c` is not a constant expression unless both `b` and `c` are, which they're not in your case. If you declared both of them `final`, then your example would work.

Answer (score 3):

Data isn't going to be lost in the second case.

A byte comprises the values of -128 and 127 inclusive, so as long as your int fits within that range, no loss of precision can occur.

Your second value is not a [`float`-literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2); by default, all floating point values in Java are `double`.  You can explicitly make that a `float` by adding `f` to the end of it.

```
float f = 2573.2211f;
```

Comment: I though so too, but `float f = 0.5;` is not accepted either, even though there is no data loss by switching from float to double.

Comment: Again - that's not a float literal.  If you want a float-literal, you need to add the lower-case f at the end (so it'd be `float f = 0.5f;`.

Comment: I know. my point is that `0.5` is a double, but it would fit in a float without data loss.

Answer (score 0):

`int` is a 32-bit signed integer, byte is an 8-bit signed integer. A `byte` runs from -128 to 127, while a `int` runs from -2147483648 to 2147483647

Precision isn't lost, but do not cast a big `int` into a small `byte` or you will lose data.