# No implicit casting for arithmetic assignment?

Tags: java, implicit-conversion

In JLS 5.2, which deals with narrowing conversions, it says:

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of
>   type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the
>   variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant
>   expression is representable in the type of the variable. ...

["In other words, for the non-long integer-like values, you can implicitly narrow them iff the value you're narrowing is a constant that fits within the type you're specifying."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27404624/assign-int-to-byte-vs-double-to-float-in-java)

```
  byte a = 1; // declare a byte
  a = a*2; //  you will get error here
```

In the first statement, integer `1` which is in the range of a byte is assigned to the byte `a` and there is implicit casting.

In the second statement, byte `a` of value 1 is multiplied by an integer `2`. Because of the arithmetic rules in Java, the byte `a` of value 1 is converted to an integer of value 1. The result of multiplying these two integers (1*2) is the integer 2.

Why is there no implicit conversion in the second statement which results in an error?

```
Main.java:14: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
  a = a*2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, in your example, `a*2` is not a [constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

It would be a constant expression if `a` referred to a [constant variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4):

```
final byte a = 1;
byte b = a * 2; // compiles fine
```